# Межстраничное объявление в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, admob

Как добавить межстраничный баннер в фрагмент? Получилось добавить тестовый баннер в обычное активити, но не добавляется в фрагмент.  Какие отличия могут быть между добавление в обычное активити и в фрагмент?
Делал по этой документации:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=ru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде надо поменять
`mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);`
на `mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());`.